# Pass some value from asp.net mvc to jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, tag-it

I use asp.net mvc, jquery and [tag-it](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it) which is jquery plugin.

I want to pass some value from asp.net mvc to jquery and then to my controller, How I can do this?

This is my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var sampleTags = new Array();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/mp3/TagSuggestion',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        failure: function () { alert('Error contacting service!'); },
        success: function (data) {
            for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                sampleTags[j] = data[j];
            }
            $('#allowSpacesTags').tagit({
                availableTags: sampleTags,                
                allowSpaces: true
            });
        }
    });
});
```

This is my controller

```
    public JsonResult TagSuggestion(string id)

    {           

        IQueryable<string> tabs = mp3.TagSuggestion(id);

        return Json(tabs, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

This is my Models

```
        public IQueryable<string> TagSuggestion(string term)

    {

        IQueryable<string> tabs = from s in db.tblTags.Where(c => c.Title.Contains(term)) select s.Title;

        return tabs;

    }
```

And this is my HTML

```
<form>

        <input type="text" name="tags" id="mySingleField />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Comment: TagSuggestion isn't your Controller. It is your Controller's action aka method. Is "mp3" your Controller?

Comment: Andrew Whitaker: I want when my user input some letterin the textbox I want to give him a list of word that match that letter.

Comment: Lews Therin: I update my post the the Models.

Comment: @drammar, do you want to pass the id parameter from you javascript to controller? If yes how are you getting this id in view?

Comment: @Kundan Singh Chouhan .. yes I want to do this .. but I do not know how to get this id from view to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Set the type from POST to GET in the function. To send the id of current model, define the data argument in current function some thing like this :

```
$(function () {
    var sampleTags = new Array();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/mp3/TagSuggestion',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { id : $("#mySingleField").val() },
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        failure: function () { alert('Error contacting service!'); },
        success: function (data) {
            for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                sampleTags[j] = data[j];
            }
            $('#allowSpacesTags').tagit({
                availableTags: sampleTags,                
                allowSpaces: true
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this will fix

Comment: Thanks .. I get Error in this line data: { id : '@Model.Id' }.
I want to get ths id from this html where user will write his tag(<ul id="allowSpacesTags"></ul>)

Comment: @drammar, The error means that View Model doesn't contain the id property. did you store this id in a particular field? if yes then provide the exact html in which it stored.

Comment: I want to take the id from here where user will write it
<input name="tags" id="mySingleField"> not from View Model sorry for not begin very clear.

Comment: View Model means the model defined for this view. Also "<input name="tags" id="mySingleField">" in this field where user will write the id? Provide the exact html.

Comment: This is the exact html  <input type="text" name="tags" id="mySingleField />
as you can see it is a text box, user will write "a" latter for example then I will sent this "a" to jquery and jquery will ask my control to search for tag that contain latter "a" and will send the result back to jquery.

Comment: @drammar, i have updated my answer. I did the modification in data option according to requirement. Have a look

Comment: Thanks you but it does not work .. how the jquery will know that user wrote something? this code will work only if the id was contain anything when page loads  but what about what will happen after that ? I mean when user write something in this text box. I need to write a code that fire  every time user write something in a text box.